# tuple indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, syntax-error, depth-first-search

I keep getting that error on line:

```
state = node["state"]
```

However this works:

```
print node["state"]
```

When getting the type I get:

```
print(type(node))
--><type 'dict'>
--><type 'tuple'>
```

Here is the full code:

```
explored = dict()
state = problem.getStartState()
frontier = util.Stack()

node = {}
node["parent"] = None
node["action"] = None
node["state"] = state

frontier.push(node)

while not frontier.isEmpty():

  node = frontier.pop()
  state = node["state"]

  if problem.isGoalState(state) == True:
        break

  if state in explored:
       continue

  explored[state] = True




 class Stack:

   def __init__(self):
   self.list = []

   def push(self,item):
     self.list.append(item)

   def pop(self):
     return self.list.pop()
```

Comment: You redefined `node` as `node = frontier.pop()` which is probably a tuple :)

Comment: What is `util.Stack`? Did you implement your own stack ADT? Why not just use a Python `list`? My guess is that, whatever this `util.Stack` is, it returns a tuple that has the element itself as well as some other information of some sort

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried printing `node` before you try doing `node['state']`?

Comment: I updated the post with the code for the stack

Comment: have you implemented isEmpty in Stack?

Comment: yep, forgot to include it in the excerpt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really looks like you have a tuple there, not a dict as you expect.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def push(self,item):
        self.list.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.list.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.list) == 0

state = 'blah'
explored = dict()
frontier = Stack()

node = {}
node["parent"] = None
node["action"] = None
node["state"] = state

frontier.push(node)

while not frontier.isEmpty():

  node = frontier.pop()
  print(type(node)) # <--- NEW
  state = node["state"]

  #if problem.isGoalState(state) == True:
        #break

  #if state in explored:
       #continue

  explored[state] = True
```

This code returns only a `<class 'dict'>` - thus there might be something in list you are not aware of

Comment: On "print (type(node))" I get 

    <type 'dict'>
     <type 'tuple'>

Comment: @HashimSalem so at the second iteration you find a tuple - which means you pushed that in somehow before the 'state'

Comment: Got it, Thanks alot